# segmentation fault core dumped in hermite

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, coredump

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{
  int n, i, j;
  float x[10] = { 0 }, fx[10] = { 0 }, f1x[10] = { 0 }, z[20] = { 0 }, q[20][20] = { 0 };

  printf("Enter the number of initial values\n");

  scanf("%d", &n);

  printf("Enter the x values\n");

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++);

  scanf("%f", &x[i]);

  printf("Enter the fx values\n");

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++);

  scanf("%f", &fx[i]);

  printf("Enter the f1x values\n");

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++);

  scanf("%f", &f1x[i]);

  for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
  {
    z[2 * i] = x[i];

    z[(2 * i) + 1] = x[i];

    q[2 * i][0] = fx[i];

    q[(2 * i) + 1][0] = fx[i];

    q[(2 * i) + 1][1] = f1x[i];

    if (i != 0)
    {
      q[2 * i][1] = (q[2 * i][0] - q[(2 * i) - 1][0]) / (z[2 * i] - z[(2 * i) - 1]);
    }
  }
  for (i = 2; i < (2 * n) + 1; i++)
  {
    for (j = 2; j < i; i++)
    {
      q[i][j] = (q[i][j - 1] - q[i - 1][j - 1]) / (z[i] - z[i - j]);
    }
  }
  printf("\nthe resultant matrix is\n");
  for (i = 0; i < (2 * n) + 2; i++)
    printf("   %f   ", q[i][i]);
}
```

when i run the program and take the number of initial values (say 3) then it asks for 1 x then asks for fx and f1x and givves segmentation error
.

Comment: Kindly format the code. Then use a debugger to step through the program to find out the erroneous statement.

Comment: You should take care about `;` at end of `for` loop; (i.e) delete the `;`.

Comment: ya i deleted ; in the for loops .. still the problem persists

Comment: So update your post to reflect this. And while you're at it, fix the indention to something sane and readable.

Comment: ya but why wont it take the rest 2 inputs from me?

Comment: while editing here it says your post has mostly code and doesnt accept my edit

Comment: amongst other things, this data init statement: q[20][20] = { 0 } is not correct, it should be: q[20][20] = {{0,0}};

Comment: the variables x[10[ and fx[10] and f1x[10] are only allocating space for 10 entries,  what happens if 'n' is larger than 10? undefined behaviour (including seg faulting)

Comment: if n = 10, then this line: for (i = 2; i < (2 * n) + 1; i++) would run the 'i' value from 2 through 20 however, an array is accessed as 0 through arraysize-1, to this will access beyond the end of the 'q' array, = undefined behaviour (including seg faulting)

Comment: this line: q[i][j] = (q[i][j - 1] - q[i - 1][j - 1]) / (z[i] - z[i - j]); fails to handle q[0][x] and q[x][0]  so those values would not be updated

Comment: this code block, beginning with: for (j = 2; j < i; i++) never increments the 'j' value, but does increment the 'i',  so 1) this loop will never exit 2) as 'i' gets large enough, it will access beyond the end of the q[] array, resulting in undefined behaviour (including seg faulting)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a wrong increment value in the inner loop:

```
for (i = 2; i<(2 * n) + 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 2; j<i; i++) <- this should be j
```

and thus accessing out-of-range memory.

Answer (score 1):

If you'd use proper indention, code formatting and always used braces after selection/loop statements, you'd soon find out that the problem is the semicolons you have typed after each for loop.

Answer (score 0):

It is not safe at all:

```
int n;
float x[10];

printf("Enter the number of initial values\n");
scanf("%d",&n);

printf("Enter the x values\n");
for(i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    scanf("%f",&x[i]);
}
```

If user enters `50` for `n`, you will get a segmentation fault in your loop as `x` as only room for `10` values. You should consider using `malloc` to reserve space for your arrays.